# MVC - Trying to get input from HTML in a Controller on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the input from **all** the HTML objects I used in the view to run some other functions with those inputs.

I need to get the input from

- A textbox
- 3 selects (comboboxes)

This is what I do on button click:

Controll (Controller is called "SetupController"):

```html
        public ActionResult Install()
        {
            return View("Index"); //This is my home-page
        }
```

HTML:

```html
@Html.ActionLink("Start Setup!", "Install", "Setup")
```

So how do I get information out of those inputs?

The selects are called "folder", "database" and "sbnProject".

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to fix it (after a while of trying):

```
    // GET: Configuration
    public ActionResult Install(String projectName, FormCollection selectLists)
    {

        var var1 = selectLists["svnProject"];
        var var2 = selectLists["database"];
        var var3 = selectLists["folder"];

        return View("Index");

    }
```

Have fun with the answer!